# simple pandas merge has unexpected results - get data structure but not expected data

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm getting unexpected results - my merge includes 2 columns in 1 table, 3 columns in another with a common column between them. Merge returns the expected 3 column data structure, but only the results from one side of the merge (basically a copy of one side of the data), so one field has no values unless I do an outer join. If I do an inner join, I get no values - even though I can clearly see values in common.
Have used on_left and on_right with same results. No columns are indexed.

I am using Pandas v 1.0.3

`DFA.merge(DFB, on=['queue'],  how='left').fillna('').drop_duplicates()` results in

```
(illustrative - not actual results)
queue  group   app
Q1        G1
Q2        G2
Q3        G2
Q4
Q5        G4
Q5        G6
```

`DFA.merge(DFB, on=['queue'],  how='right').fillna('').drop_duplicates()` results in

```
(illustrative - not actual results)
app queue   group
10  Q1
20  Q3
30  Q3
40  Q4
10
```

`DFA.merge(DFB, on=['queue'],  how='inner').fillna('').drop_duplicates()` results in

```
(actual results)
```

yeah, no results

This seems pretty simple - what am I missing here? The values in the queue file are verified to be exactly the same in excel. data types are all objects (strings)

Comment: FWIW, I've set the encoding to 'utf-8' on read and in the file ```.str.encode('utf-8') ``` and encoding='utf-8'```

Answer (score 0):

The user striped the spaces off the data and then showed me that the data matched, then sent me the file w/o saving it so the data still had spaces.

**never trust any inputs**

The code was fine.